# Would drinking excessive coffee reduce blood hemoglobin content?

Tags: health

Would drinking excessive coffee, such as 4-5 20oz cups (100 fl.oz. / 3 L total) per day, reduce blood hemoglobin content?

Are there other digestion or gastric issues related to drinking excessive coffee?

Comment: Golly, for my consumption level, I certainly hope not. 100 fl. oz. / 3L of coffee is certainly not modest but not completely crazy. What makes you think this is the case? Would you please edit your question to link to citations or references to suggest why you suspect that coffee might impact hemoglobin levels?

Comment: Please focus on one topic per question; would you kindly split the other topic about digestion/gastric issues into a separate question, annotated with specific concerns?

Comment: @hoc_age , I drink atleast 3 large cup of coffee... and the topic is same related to health ...

Comment: @goofyui There are technically two questions in your post, one about blood hemoglobin content effects and another about gastric or digestive system effects of excessive coffee drinking. Although both about health, they are two different questions and should strictly be separated.

Answer (score 1):

coffee reduces iron uptake. parts of hemoglobin are comprised of iron. if hemoglobin becomes low the oxygen rate to other parts of your body decrease. causing low energy and fatigue. the low iron could also cause anemia.

Comment: Thank you, I will control my coffee intake

Comment: Hey @russman6, thanks for the information. Could you please support your claim with a source? Therefore, people could be sure that this is not just a claim but based on facts.

Comment: no worries mate, i researched the information on the internet for you. next time ill post the sources.